# Javascript - How do I improve performance when animating integers?

Tags: javascript, performance, repaint

On the site I'm working on, we collect data from a datasource and present these in their own design element, in the form of an SVG. The SVG files are renamed to .php in order to insert the dynamic data from the datasource.

Then, I'm using [inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) javascript to initialize a function that animates the data from the source, from 0 to their actual value. However, I notice this gets kinda heavy on the browser, when there are a lot of elements that are running the animate function.

Is there perhaps a smarter way of doing this? I haven't really dug that much into it, because it's not that bad. I just happened to notice the lag when scrolling through the area being repainted.

Here's my js code:

```
    $('.inview article').bind('inview', function(event, isInView, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
          if (isInView) {
            // element is now visible in the viewport
            if (visiblePartY == 'top' || visiblePartY == 'both' || visiblePartY == 'bottom') {
                var $this = $(this);
                var element = $($this);


                $this.addClass('active');
                reinitializeText(element);
                $this.unbind('inview');

              // top part of element is visible
            } else if (visiblePartY == 'bottom') {
            } else {
            }
          } else {
          }
        });

function reinitializeText(element) {

    var svg = element.find('svg');  
    var children = svg.children('.infographics_svg-text');

    // If there is no class in svg file, search other elements for the class
    if (children.length == 0) {
        var children = element.find('.infographics_svg-text');
    }

    children.each(function (){
        var step = this.textContent/100;
        var round = false;

        if (this.textContent.indexOf('.') !=-1) {
            round = true;
        }

        animateText(this, 0, step, round);
    });
}

function animateText(element, current, step, round) {
    if (current > 100) return;
    var num = current++ *step;

    if (round) {
        num = Math.round((num)*100)/100
    } else {
        num = Math.round(num);
    }

    element.textContent = num;
    setTimeout(function() {
        animateText(element, current, step, round);
    }, 10);
}
```

Edit: Because of the difference in data values received from the source (low numbers to huge numbers), The speed of the animation is increased so it doesn't go on forever

Comment: Then, why don't you try to use a single `animateText`?

Comment: I believe the smart way of going about it is by using [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) (only paint once per frame). I haven't used that much tho, so I can't give you an example on how to use it in your situation.

Comment: @Alexander The idea is that isn't only supposed to animate when the svg is in view. I'll look into requestAnimationFrame(), I've read about it regarding performace before :)